# Dell XPS m1530 overheating problem

Tags: dell, overheating, fan, temperature, heat

I have a Dell XPS m1530 running Ubuntu 13.10 and began noticing the keyboard surface get hot. It seemed odd to me that the fan runs intermittently at lower temperatures. I've already checked the wiring and heat sink paste inside the machine, after which, the CPU and GPU were both at 200F. Occasionally, my computer will shut down due to overheating.

Is there any way to solve this issue without buying a new machine altogether?

Answer (score 0):

The GPU is known to overheat on the XPS M1530, there are a couple of things that you can do.

1. Service the heatsink (remove the fluff etc) and replace the heatsink paste with Artic Silver. This is not guaranteed to fix the issue, but some people have had success with this.
2. Replace the motherboard with one which has the later revision of the GPU, this is the more expensive approach.

I had written a set of instructions for the above. Here they are:

[Dell XPS M1530 Heatsink Removal and Refitting and Servicing](https://fixitfriends.com/fixits/dell-xps-m1530-heatsink-removal-and-refitting-and-servicing)

[Dell XPS M1530 Motherboard Replacement](https://fixitfriends.com/fixits/dell-xps-m1530-motherboard-replacement)